# Is a world of only time a world without intelligible order?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics, schopenhauer

We live in a world of three spatial dimensions and one of time; what this means is now obvious given the extent science and mathematics has entered popular discourse.

Whenever we have a number we can reduce or increase it; hence we have for example the short novella by Abbot -  *Flatland* we are asked to contemplate a world with only two dimensions; ie life lived in the plane; likewise one could envisage a book, and I'm confident that one, and most likely dozens (for example Heinleins *By his Bootstraps*) where life is lived in four or more space dimensions.

But what would life be like were we to live only in space? without time, there could be no change; so as Schopenhauer puts it (*Die Welt*):

> if the world were in space alone, it would be rigid and immoveable; without succession, without change; and without change.

This is quite natural to see this; but how would a world solely in time look like? Again Schpoenhauer writes:

> All would be fleeting, without contiguity, hence without co-existence and consequently without Permenance; so that on this case there is no matter.

This is harder to concieve; perhaps we are less likely to try to concieve it; still contiguity in space as co-existence is understood; but how from this follows permenance?

For Schopenhauer permenance is the condition of matter - it persists whilst changing.

But there is another notion of permenance; which is the notion of the hidden intelligible order; but given this is what conditions the dynamics of matter one might identify this with the permenance of Schopenhauers.

Can we then suppose a world that is only of time is one way of conceiving a world of no intelligible order; ie of no permenance?

Comment: In a world without extent, how would one take measurements? In a world without measurements, how would one detect differences? In a world without differences, how could one observe change? In a world without change, what would *time* mean?

Comment: @Bron: I agree that space and time are hardly conceivable without each other; still an ideal picture can be given as Schopenhauer does for a world without time.

Comment: If you think about simulating a spacetime and you remove all space dimensions, well then it gets rather difficult to define the distances between things. Or put another way, the distances between things, define a space. With no distances you only get simple time-varying effects, such as random decays of particles. It's pretty dull and uninteresting. Click! Oh, a particle decayed. Click click click! Oh my, three in a row! Waiting, waiting… Zzzzz…

Comment: **-1** The question fails to mention that the OP is interested in the discussion of two (or more) time dimensions, instead of zero space dimensions as mentioned, and the OP is rude about it.

Comment: I've removed many off-topic comments from this thread. If you want a discussion, I recommend [chat]

Comment: @DanBron  You can have states of variation that are not extensive.  The cheap example is color.  We can draw four-dimensional pictures of Complex functions in two dimensions by allowing the parameters to be drawn in the plane and the function values to be represented by intensity (for the magnitude) and hue (for the argument), and we still have two dimensions to play with to detail a Riemann surface (saturation and depth).  Why not seven or eight color-attribute-like dimensions and no spatial ones?

Comment: @jobermark  color is made of wavelengths. It is the difference in the *lengths of those waves* that give rise to color. Similarly, color requires a *surface* to reflect off of. And processing: without physical rods and cones to capture the photons and neurons to interpret the excitement of the resulting electrons, color doesn't exist. And so on. If you go brought the thought experiment of picking apart any example of "dimensionless change" you can come up with, I believe you'll reach the same conclusion. Space without time *might* be meaningful. But time without space is meaningless.

Comment: @DanBron All of that physics has no basis if you are talking about two-dimensional worlds to start off with.  In fact, it has no representation in three dimensions.: the 'waving' of a particle is about oscillation of something that is not physically represented in 3-space.  Phase is like hue only 720 degrees around.  Why would that disappear in lower-dimensional space?  The question is, as I see it, mathematical and not physical. Mathematically, color is just a group of continuua represented without extension in space.

Comment: @jobermark I think I've misunderstood the question: isn't the OP asking not about a *two* dimensional (Flatland)  universe, nor even a 1D universe, but a literal *spaceless*, 0+T universe? No space *at all*. That completely changes the game. Not only is there nothing to oscillate *around*, there is nothing to oscillate *in*. Oscillation is a senseless idea in 0D. It means nothing.

Comment: @DanBron  But the oscillation that particles undergo is not motion in space, anyway, it is some kind of magical "rotational energy" that **does not have a radius to rotate around**.  There is no way in which that nonsense is tied to how many dimensions there are.

Comment: @jobermark My thought is we're going in circles here. The concept of *particle* requires spatial dimensions. You can't have particles - not even point particles, not even a singularity - in 0D. And light is literally measured in *wave**lengths***, nanometers. No amount of handwaving will make that go away. Time requires change requires difference requires measurement requires dimensions aka space. That's it. Signing off now.

Comment: OK, but what is that *length* the length of?  It is the speed of light divided by a frequency of rotation of a point, which has no radius and therefore is not really rotating.  It is the distance light covers between points where it is in the same phase.  But phase of what -- something dimensionless.

Comment: @DanBron: your later comment is correct, I am asking about 0+T spacetime; and I go along with you in supposing that increasing or decreasing the space dimensions  is meaningful; apart from zero dimensions; where there is literally nothing that can move; so no possible idea of time, yet I've supposed time; hence contradiction; and thus meaningless.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24463/discussion-on-question-by-mozibur-ullah-is-a-world-of-only-time-a-world-without).

Answer (score 1):

In "Geometry, Relativity and the Fourth Dimension", Rudy Rucker does a passable job of extending Abbot, taking us first to a more compelling version of flatland, then to a circular one-dimensional space, and to a point space, and keeping our ability to interpret characters in those spaces.  The relatable version of a being in zero dimensions, to the degree you find his cartoons compelling, has only the experience of being in various internal states, and a "stream of consciousness" about passing between those.

You have to ignore where the memory to maintain the stream would dwell, but from an idealist standpoint we do not know that our minds do not extend into more dimensions than we perceive.  We have the ability to think reasonably about four dimensions.  From the points of view of some of Rucker's characters, there is an argument that we only have a three-dimensional experience and not a three-dimensional mind.

Given memory, a point-universe being could have the ability to expect recurrence, which is a form of your second kind of permanence.  So I believe you can say it is not necessarily impossible to have permanence in the broader meaning in a zero-dimensional space with time even if it is impossible in Schopenhauer's sense since no two things can exist at the same time in zero dimensions.